# Convertir celdas a mayúsculas

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy trabajando con DataTables, tengo un ajax que me devuelve objetos en minúsculas y otras en mayúsculas. Pero quiero que todas las celdas estén en mayúsculas.

Aquí recepciono la data del api.

```
columns: [
                {data: "manifestado"},
                {data: "nave"},
                {data: "tipo_nave"},
                {data: "nombre_linea"},
                {data: "nro_viaje"},
                {data: "agente_maritimo"},
                {data: "eslora"},
                {data: "eta"},
                {data: "etb"},
                {data: "etc"},
                {data: "etd"},
                {data: "carga"},
                {data : "proyecto_articulo"}
            ],
```

Si necesitan alguna otra información(código), se las pasaré.

Gracias

Comment: Está solucionado:

Cogí el ID  de mi dataTables y mediante css puse:
```
 #example{
                text-transform: uppercase !important;
            }

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es más fácil agregando css al elemento que quieras pasar a mayúsculas.

Puedes utulizar la propiedad text-transform: uppercase; ya sea que lo pongas directamente en la etiqueta o en una clase.

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no se puede.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no se puede?

Comment: Transformar los objetos a mayúsculas.

Comment: Me retracto, disculpe, soy muy noob en esto.

Estas en lo correcto,  cogí el id de mi datatables  y bueno puse lo que me recomendaste.
` #example{
                text-transform: uppercase !important;
            }`
Gracias

Comment: Que bien!! ¿puedes poner mi respuesta como tu solución a tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Además del atributo `data` debes añadir el atributo `render`, que es una función que espera los parámetros `item`, `type` y `row`. Para tu caso en realidad sólo necesitas el `item`:

```
columns: [{
    data: "manifestado",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "nave",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "tipo_nave",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "nombre_linea",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "nro_viaje",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "agente_maritimo",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "eslora",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "eta",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "etb",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "etc",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "etd",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "carga",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    data: "proyecto_articulo",
    render: function (item) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Al utilizar lo que me recomiendas me tira este error. 


*Uncaught TypeError: item.toUpperCase is not a function*

La verdad soy novato con todo esto, pero estoy investigando a fondo y estoy logrando varias cosas.

Comment: Pensándolo bien, si alguno de los campos es numérico, no debes tratar de pasarlo a mayúsculas

Comment: Lo intenté con un campo de tipo cadena y me vota ese error.

Comment: Y qué dice si antes haces `console.log(item)`?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías considerar que se visualice en mayúscula con una clase de estilo o al momento de renderizar las celdas.

Utilizando estilo:

```
tr[role="row"] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Al momento de renderizar:

```
"columnDefs": [{
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            return data.toUpperCase();
        },
        "targets": "_all"
    }
]
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [
              {
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {                      
                      return data.toUpperCase();
                  },
                  "targets": "_all"
              }
          ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
tr[role="row"] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Hola</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Mundo</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>            
</table>
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [columnDefs.targets](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets)

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas mapearlos con el método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).

```js
const data = { 
 columns: [
  { data: "manifestado" },
  { data: "nave" },
  { data: "tipo_nave" },
  { data: "nombre_linea" },
  { data: "nro_viaje" },
  { data: "agente_maritimo" },
  { data: "eslora" },
  { data: "eta" },
  { data: "etb" },
  { data: "etc" },
  { data: "etd" },
  { data: "carga" },
  { data : "proyecto_articulo" }
 ]
};

data.columns = data.columns.map(col => ({ data: col.data.toUpperCase() }));

console.log(data.columns);
```